# Where are log files in deployed Clojure web app

Tags: logging, clojure, web-deployment, luminus

I've developed a small Clojure web app in Luminus and am now trying to deploy it on my local machine (Mac OS X Sierra). I've followed the guide on http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/deployment.md and successfully compiled it to both a standalone jar-file (`lein uberjar`) and a tomcat war-file (`lein uberwar`).

But when I run it I get a 500 server error, both the standalone and tomcat. I would like to inspect the log files to see whats going on but I can't find them anywhere. Anyone know where standalone apps and/or tomcat war-files place their log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed this section [logging_configuration](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/logging.md#logging_configuration) with it you can configure location of your logs for Luminus